# How to Check Adobe AIR applications performance ?Any tools?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

Hi I'm creating an adobe AIR application..Its working fine ,But I want to make my application without performance  issues..How to Check Adobe AIR applications performance ?Is there any tools available?

Comment: Are you building a Flex Application?

Comment: @ www.Flextras.com :Yes I'm creating an application with flex  and Actionscript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [**Adobe Scout**](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/)

"Adobe Scout is the next-generation profiling tool for Adobe Flash Player and AIR."

Comment: Definately Scout.  But know that Scout only runs on 64-bit systems and it requires Flash Player 11.5 / AIR 3.5 or higher.  Also, FlashDevelop isn't yet compatible with Scout since it doesn't support the new compiler, but it will be coming.  In the meantime, you can do on-device profiling using a plugin (http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=10322) or simply just use your desktop for a more general, less precise, profile of your code.

Comment: I didn't know about the Adobe Scout before, but it sounds promising. I'll definately try it soon.

Answer (score 3):

1. When building any flash application you define the application FPS. If the real FPS (flash can skip frames under high load) is lower than the defined FPS- you have troubles. You can check the FPS by vast variety of FPS meters [here](https://www.google.ru/search?q=actionscript+fps+meter).
   If your real FPS coinsides with the defined one - it is great, but try rising the defined FPS value up to 120 (which is max) and check out the real value, it is hardly be higher than 60 during animations, but the higher you can get - the better your application is. With this approach you can eliminate or at least point out "slow code".
   **ADD:** It also worth mentioning that if the defined FPS value is 24, and the application is in stable state (the amount of animation, animation complexity and computational complexity stay more or less the same) the real value will "float" across some value, let's say 23 FPS  with the spread of 1-2 (i.e. 22.7, 23.5, 23.9, 23.1, etc). And the mean value will be always lower than the defined FPS value.
2. Try to check memory usage. I would start trying to launch Flash Builder profiler remotely while your app is running live on the device and check out memory utilization. [Refer this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7e46.html)
3. Try to check redraw regions. Note that MovieClips that are not visible (e.g. throbbers) are still redrawing unless the are stopped. So if you see some region redraws without sencible reason - try to figure out why. The ideal case is to call `stop()` and `visible=false` or remove from stage the unused animations.
   **ADD:** Redraw regions indicator is a part of Debug version of Flash Player. You can enable it through the context menu of the debug version of Flash Player.

**UPDATE:** I added some details to my answer as I see the interest to the Adobe Flash Perfomance issue. I don't remember the exact acticle, but I found a lot of usefull advices on the Abode's site, now I see that [the number of such articles there increased.](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/search/index.cfm?term=flash%20perfomance)
Also I didn't know about the Adobe Scout before, but it sounds promising. I'll definately try it soon.

Comment: As a bit of extra info; a Flex Application is set to 24 frames per second by default. In my experience it is rare that people try to change that.  The original poster tagged this as Flex; but didn't specify the type of application he is building.

Comment: It's worth noting that just about any process being run by Flash will result in a performance hit on the FPS. Losing a few frames while doing something interactive is normal behavior. Losing 25%? Not so much. If you lose that much, you should look at what you are doing that is causing it and how to optimize it.